# Can someone explain canSum to me please

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming

The question states:

> Write a function `canSum(targetSum, numbers)` that takes in a `targetSum` and an array of numbers as arguments. The function should return a boolean indicating whether or not it is possible to generate the `targetSum` using numbers from the array. You may use an element of an array as many times as needed. You may assume that all numbers are nonnegative.

In the dynamic programming video I am watching the solution is:

```
const canSum = (targetSum, numbers) => {
  if (targetSum === 0) return true;
  if (targetSum < 0) return false;

  for (let num of numbers) {
    const remainder = targetSum - num;
    if (canSum(remainder, numbers) === true) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

I understand how this code works with many scenarios like `canSum(7, [2, 3])`. However I don't understand this piece: `if (targetSum === 0) return true;` that means `canSum(0, [2, 3])` will result in true. That's not how this code should work according to the question. What am I missing here?

Thank you

```
console.log(canSum(7, [2, 4]))
```

resulted in false

however

```
console.log(canSum(0, [2]))
```

resulted in true

Comment: Your code is JavaScript, why is this tagged `c`?

Comment: that was a mistake i untagged it thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it says you can use any numbers as many times as you want, that includes using all of them *zero* times, and when you do this the sum is `0`. Using this as the base case of the recursion simplifies the algorithm, since you just keep subtracting until you get to `0`.

An alternative way would be to use `numbers.includes(targetSum)` as the base case. They're equivalent because when this is true, one of the iterations of the `for` loop will set `remainder` to `0`, and the recursive call will have `targetSum === 0`.

Comment: While this is probably the rationale behind the provided solution, I don't think it matches with the problem description. "The function should return a boolean indicating whether or not it is possible to generate the `targetSum` using numbers from the array." In this interpretation, the case for zero means no numbers from the array are used so the result should be `false`.

Comment: I disagree. This definition allows a number of invariants to work correctly. It's similar to the reason why `Array.some()` is always true when the array is empty.

Comment: That's right. The question does not state that you have to use all the numbers, or any for that matter. So I would see it as "using only the numbers provided"; like, "you cannot use numbers that are not in the list", not like "you should use the numbers in the list". I think for a "programming question" is a bit vage, as it can for sure be misinterpreted, but the interpretation given in the solution makes more sense to me.